# Excel: объединить интервалы по месяцам в ячейку и сделать автофильтр по ней

Tags: excel

Есть график отпусков, где по каждому сотруднику проставлены три отпуска за 2020 год - три интервала.

Например,

```
[АБ]  [10.01.2020][23.01.2020]  [01.07.2020][14.07.2020]  [01.12.2020][07.12.2020]
[ВГ]  [15.04.2020][28.04.2020]  [01.09.2020][14.09.2020]  [15.10.2020][21.10.2020]
```

Каждая дата - в отдельной ячейке.

Нужно сделать автофильтр по месяцам. Например, выбрали сентябрь, и на странице остались только сотрудники, у которых есть отпуск в сентябре (в примере это "ВГ").

Как я вижу решение: сделать какую-то ячейку, в которой будут перечислены все месяцы отпуска по сотруднику. И как-то сделать автофильтр по этому делу.

Устраивает любой вариант. Может макрос какой-то написать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно небольшой формулы в доп. столбце (столбец включить в фильтр):

```
=ИЛИ(МЕСЯЦ(B2:G2)=H$1)
```

Формула для строки 2, в *H1* - номер месяца. При совпадении указанного месяца с месяцем любой из дат в строке - *ИСТИНА*

Т.к. это формула массива, вводить ее нужно определенным способом.

После записи формулы, не выходя из режима редактирования, нажать три клавиши - *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. Формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками. После этого протянуть формулу на нужное количество строк.

Обычная формула (также подойдет для периодов больше 2-х месяцев):

```
=ИЛИ(И(МЕСЯЦ(B2)<=H$1;МЕСЯЦ(C2)>=H$1);
   И(МЕСЯЦ(D2)<=H$1;МЕСЯЦ(E2)>=H$1);
   И(МЕСЯЦ(F2)<=H$1;МЕСЯЦ(G2)>=H$1))
```

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Но формула не работает для [01.01.2020][18.02.2020].

Comment: Не верю ) Показывать нужно.

Comment: Если подставить в формулу `=ИЛИ(И(МЕСЯЦ(B2)>=H$1;МЕСЯЦ(C2)<=H$1);
     И(МЕСЯЦ(D2)>=H$1;МЕСЯЦ(E2)<=H$1);
     И(МЕСЯЦ(F2)>=H$1;МЕСЯЦ(G2)<=H$1)`, то `И(МЕСЯЦ(B2)>=H$1;МЕСЯЦ(C2)<=H$1)` раскладывается как `И(1>=1; 2<=1)`, что есть ложь. [Пример](https://transfer.sh/rojcm/filter.xlsx)

Comment: Ну да, извините. Нужно поменять знаки неравенства.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поправьте ответ, я его отмечу как решение. Я сейчас пришел к верному решению, когда нарисовал интервалы на листе.

Comment: Формула в ответе исправлена